# Get the child input tag for the current checkbox clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope

I am trying to get the child input tag for the current checkbox that is clicked and add `checked` to it through my directive. I have the directive setup correctly but I am getting `undefined` when I try to get `elem[1]`

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked ng-model="checkboxoption.value1">
    <span class="custom"></span>
    <label for="checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.directive('checkbox', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.bind('click', function(evt) {
                var currentCheckbox = elem[1];
                console.log(elem[1]);
                elem.prop('checked');
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elem` is a jQuery or jqLite object.  The subscript lets you index into the collection of elements matched by a selector.  So for example, in jQuery,

```
$("span")[1]
```

gets the second `span` on the page.  On the other hand,

```
$("body")[1]
```

should return undefined because there should only be one body.

There is only one element (the `<div class="checkbox">`) in `elem`.  To get its second child, you can do this:

```
elem.children()[1]
```

But you probably want its first child, since the checkbox comes first in your HTML:

```
elem.children()[0]
```

Another approach is:

```
elem.find("input")[0]
```

That may be better since it won't break if you change the order of the elements in your HTML.

Both of these will get you a plain DOM object.  Once you have the checkbox element, you can set its `checked` attribute like this:

```
elem.children()[0].checked = true;
// or
elem.find("input")[0].checked = true;
```

By the way, you should probably remove the `id` element from your checkbox, because if you use this directive more than once, the ID will be duplicated.

Comment: Makes sense but still doesn't answer my second question of adding checked into it... I have tried using `prop` to do so

Comment: @user4756836 Edited

Comment: Use the same checked property

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do like this using [Angular#angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element);

You can get the current checked element using [jQuery#target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property of event

```
 link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            elem.bind('click', function(evt) {
            angular.element(evt.target).attr('checked',true);
       });
 }
```

Here is the working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/j6f28DzSfwXUcvRopBvl?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access elem[1] which does not exist in the array elem.

Instead of using  `elem[1]` use `elem[0]`